# Efficient way to find maximum value on 80+ tables

Tags: mysql

I have a 80 tables and I want to filter who has the highest price among 80 tables. I plan on using this query:

```
SELECT id
 FROM (SELECT id, price FROM T1 WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM T1)
    UNION
    SELECT id, price FROM T2 WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM T2)
    UNION
    SELECT id, price FROM T3 WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM T3)
   ) AS M
 ORDER BY price DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

But I find it inefficient. Is there other way?

Comment: Table per client/year/region indicates a poor db design. I suggest to rethink your schema.

Comment: Simple. Don't have 80 tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a lot faster.

```
SELECT id, price FROM t1
UNION SELECT id, price FROM t2
UNION SELECT id, price FROM t3
ORDER BY price DESC 
LIMIT 1
```